# PHP: unexpected T_VARIABLE when initializing associative array

Tags: php, associative-array, parse-error

I get the following error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in *path*/queries.php on line 92

because of the array `$_queryArray` :

```
private $_queryA = "";
etc...
private $_queryV = "";


private $_queryArray = array(   'A' => $this->_queryA, //<= line 92 of my code
                                'B' => $this->_queryB,
                                'C' => $this->_queryC,
                                'D' => $this->_queryD,
                                'E' => $this->_queryE,
                                'F' => $this->_queryF,
                                'G' => $this->_queryG,
                                'H' => $this->_queryH,
                                'I' => $this->_queryI,
                                'J' => $this->_queryJ,
                                'K' => $this->_queryK,
                                'L' => $this->_queryL,
                                'M' => $this->_queryM,
                                'N' => $this->_queryN,
                                'O' => $this->_queryO,
                                'P' => $this->_queryP,
                                'Q' => $this->_queryQ,
                                'R' => $this->_queryR,
                                'S' => $this->_queryS,
                                'T' => $this->_queryT,
                                'U' => $this->_queryU,
                                'V' => $this->_queryV 
                            );
```

Is there a problem with my way of filling `$_queryArray ?`

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $this references an instance, and doesn't exist when the class is being defined, you can't use $this in property definitions

Quoting from the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: Make it an empty array, and populate it in the constructor, when yo build the queries

Comment: better yet, make it into a getter function instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the code is from within a class declaration.

My guess would be that you cannot access $this at this point.
Try setting the array in the constructor.

```
function __construct() {
    $this->_queryArray = array( ... );
}
```

Comment: Well spotted, this is still too localised though.

Comment: I could do it, but I am filling the queries in a static way before putting them in the array. It would be pretty ugly for a constructor to have 200 lines of static filling no :s ?

Comment: Those $_query_A type vars don't look particularly static to me

Comment: And you don't need 200 lines of array population, you use a loop